# can someone guide how to produce such cover pages with latex--I am interested in how the crossed lines are set

Tags: covers

`\usepackage[
  height=8in,      % height of the text block
  width=6in,       % width of the text block
  top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
  headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
  headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
  heightrounded,   % ensure an integer number of lines
%  showframe,       % show the main blocks
  showcrop=true,
  verbose,         % show the values of the parameters in the log file
]{geometry}`[image]

can someone guide how to produce such cover pages with latex--I am interested in how the crossed lines are set

Comment: The geometry package supports alignment marks using the layout and showcrop options (see page 6 and 12).  Note that the layout uses a larger paper size than the document.

Comment: Also see the crop package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to obtain a specific layout that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.